# How to redirect on the same port from http to https with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy, nginx, reverse-proxy

I use reverse proxy with Nginx and I want to force the request into HTTPS, so if a user wants to access the url with http, he will be automatically redirected to HTTPS.

I'm also using a non-standard port.

Here is my nginx reverse proxy config:

```
server {
    listen 8001  ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/xxx/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/xxx/server.key;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
    }
}
```

I've tried many things and also read posts about it, including [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom), but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: To reopen reviewers: This question is definitely related to programming, and very specific. Just that the 'non-standard port' was not mentioned before, which might have made it a little vague before.

Comment: It's downright wrong that this was closed as off topic. nginx is a common tool used in programming, and the highest rated solution present the correct code to fix the problem: `error_page 497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;`

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Found something that is working well :

```
server {
        listen 8001  ssl;
        ssl_certificate /home/xxx/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/xxx/server.key;
        error_page 497 301 =307 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
        location /{
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        }
}
```

Comment: error code 497 is created especially for this use case [redirect on the same port from http to https]. I think this is the best answer. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule#Nonstandard_error_codes

Comment: Thanks a lot!! `error_page 497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;` did the trick!

Comment: I would consider adding: `error_page 497  301 =307 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;` That way the request method isn't auto converted to a GET as is default

Comment: @Komu you saved me :)

Comment: Thanks, in my case i also had to enable the firewall

Comment: What is the meaning of 301 in `error_page 497 301 =307`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
...
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can

1. use $server_name to avoid hard coding your domain name again (DRY),
2. use return 301 for a bit easier reading (a web dev should know this http status code)

Note: I put 443 for https server. You may listen to 8001 if you really want that.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  your_hostname.com;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
...
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name your_hostname.com
    ...
}
```

Comment: well i use reverse proxy with nginx because i got different RoR environement for each apps. So i start my app with a standalone server Passanger + nginx and use a reverse proxy to add thoses SSL Certs. Because i can't add SSL Cert path with the standalone version.

Comment: If i change error_page  497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri; by return 301 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;  

I got this and the redirect is broke again.

400 Bad Request

The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Comment: I see. Your answer should be the best answer. your question is that it's going through a nonstandard port, and you want to redirect from http to https on the SAME port. So it's impossible to set up 2 server blocks like I originally thought, because you can't have 2 server blocks listening to the same port.

Comment: @senayar why not answer your own question? and I'll upvote yours. So it's easier for other people to learn from this. Also please update the question itself and state the main issue: redirecting on the same port from http to https

Comment: i can't accept my own answer in 2 days :) but it's done thank. Maybe someone can propose another solution. Thank for your help!

Answer (score -1):

This is my approach, which I think is quite clean and allows you to add further locations if needed.  I add a test on the $http_x_forwarded_proto property which if  true forces all HTTP traffic to HTTPS on a NGINX Reverse Proxy setup

```
upstream flask_bootstrap {
    server flask-bootstrap:8000;
}

server {
    # SSL traffic terminates on the Load Balancer so we only need to listen on port 80
    listen 80;

    # Set reverse proxy
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask_bootstrap;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost/;

        # Permanently redirect any http calls to https
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }
}
```