# How to force ssl/tls on nginx on a single port

Tags: nginx

I know how to redirect all http request on nginx to https, but if I am only running nginx on a non-standard port (9575) then how can I reject any connections that do not use SSL/TLS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429043/how-to-redirect-on-the-same-port-from-http-to-https-with-nginx-reverse-proxy),  this should work:

```
server {
        listen 9575 ssl;
        error_page 497 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
}
```